# Correctly getting the stack area of individual threads in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I try to get the stack areas in memory on a X64 Ubuntu 18.04 system the threads of a running process. The process is a pthread using C++ program. My current attempt consists of getting the PID of the process, then call

ps -T | grep PID

to get the SPID of the processes. Then I use

cat /proc/SPID/maps | grep stack to print the stack area.

But the output for all threads / SPID is the same. Is there a correct way to get position and size of stack area for each thread?

Regards

Comment: All threads share an address space, the stack is the main process stack.  Thread-local storage is created at runtime from the process data area.

Comment: Pthread still gives every thread its own portion. These portions I need.

Comment: Pointer to the stack is in the task_struct for the thread.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.149/source/include/linux/sched.h#L624

Comment: @stark Very good. So, is this task_struct stored somewhere on the stack or in a register on X86 in a location I can easily access via GDB?